# why does the error message not show up?

Tags: php, jquery, error-handling, image-uploading

I am very new to PHP (only been doing it since September so I apologise if this seems like a silly question, I'm very stuck and can't work out the answer!) and cannot work out why my error message does not display when a user submits the form when it is empty.

This is my code:

```
    <?php
$salonid = "";
    if (!$db_server){
            die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error($db_server));
            $db_status = "not connected";
    }else{
        //Capture form data, if anything was submitted
        if (isset($_GET['salonid']) and ($_GET['salonid'] != '')){
            $salonid = clean_string($db_server, $_GET['salonid']);
            //If connected, get Salons from database and write out
            mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database);
            $query = "SELECT ID, salon_name, address, postcode, telephone, email, website FROM salon WHERE ID=$salonid";
            $result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query); 
            if (!$result) die("Query failed: " . mysqli_error($db_server));

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                $str_result .= "<h2>" . $row[ 'salon_name'] . "</h2>";
                $str_result .= "<p>" . $row['address'] . "</p>";
                $str_result .= "<p>" . $row['postcode'] . "</p>";
                $str_result .= "<p>" . $row['telephone'] . "</p>";
                $str_result .= "<p>" . $row['email'] . "</p>";
                $str_result .= "<p>" . $row['website'] . "</p>";

            }
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }else{
            $str_result = "<h2>No salon selected</h2>";

        }

    }
    echo $str_result;
?>

<?php 

if(trim($_POST['submit']) == "Submit comment"){

    //Get any submitted comments and insert
    $comment = clean_string($db_server, $_POST['comment']);
    if ($comment != '') {
        $name=$_FILES['photo']['name'];
        if ($name = "") $error .= "<p class='error'>You must upload an image!</p>";
        $originalname=$_FILES['photo']['name'];
        $type=$_FILES['photo']['type'];
        if ($type=="image/jpeg")  $type=".jpeg"; //if true change 
        else if ($type=="image/jpg") $type=".jpg";// if not true check this one
        else if ($type=="image/png") $type=".png";
        $name=uniqid() . $type;

        $path="images/" . $name;
        $tempname=$_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
        $size=$_FILES['photo']['size'];
        //Error checking
        if ($size >1000000) $error .= "<p class='error'>Your image file is to big, it have to be less than 200 mb</p>";
        if ($error=="") {
            if (move_uploaded_file($tempname, $path)){

                $uploadquery="INSERT INTO comments (comment, imagename, salonID, userID) VALUES ('$comment', '$path', $salonid, ". $_SESSION['userID'].")";
                mysqli_query($db_server,$uploadquery) or die ("Insert failed " . mysqli_error($db_server) . " " . $uploadquery);
                $message= "<h2>Thanks for your comment!</h2><p>Your upload was succesful</p>";
            }
        }
    }

}

//Print out existing comment
$query = "SELECT * FROM comments JOIN users ON comments.userID = users.ID WHERE salonID=$salonid"; 
$result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query);
if (!$result) die("Database access failed: " . mysqli_error($db_server));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $str_comments .="<h2>" . $row['Username'] ."</h2>";
        $str_comments .= "<p>" . $row['comment'] . "</p>";
        $str_comments .="<img src='" . $row['imagename'] ."' />";
}

mysqli_free_result($result);

?>  
<div id="form">
<table><form id='review' action='salonpage.php?salonid=<?php echo $salonid; ?>' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<th><h2> Do you want to review the service you recieved?</h2></th>
<tr><td><textarea name="comment" rows="6" cols="40">Write something here!</textarea></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type='file' name='photo' accept='image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png'/></td></tr>
<br/>
<tr><td><input type='submit' id='submit' name='submit' value='Submit comment' /></td></tr>
</form></table>
<?php echo $message;
    echo $str_comments; ?>
</div>
<?php mysqli_close($db_server); ?>
```

Comment: check ``($name = "")`` correct form ``($name == "")`` - allso you use ``$error .=`` without declare ``$error``

Comment: That doesn't work, I think what I may need to do is add another if statement saying that they need to fill in all the fields

Comment: i think you should not copy paste without any knowledge and then wonder why nothing works - you need to check first if all ``POST`` values are present ``if( ! $allPresent ) { //display error  } ``

Comment: I think, you are talking about $error, if i am correct then you did not echo $error variable in your above mention code. One more thing add  else part on if block "if ($comment != '')" else {$error.="no comment entered" }

Comment: That sorted it! Thank you, I've been staring at this for about a week now without being able to sort it!

Comment: @user3095683 i have just posted my answer please accept it. Thanks

Comment: To help with your php debugging, you should ensure that the php error log is turned on, then take note of where it is located so that you can look at it to see why your code isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($comment != '') {
        $name=$_FILES['photo']['name'];
        if ($name = "") $error .= "<p class='error'>You must upload an image!</p>";
        $originalname=$_FILES['photo']['name'];
```

in this code you are using

```
$name = ""
```

which is an assignment operator you need to use comparison operator within if condition either `==`or `===`

Comment: I have updated my code to say this, however no error messages are showing up when all boxes are left blank

Comment: you need to add else conditions to throw exceptions or echo error messages to give feedback to the user.. for example if ($comment != '') {..} else {$error.="no comment entered" } otherwise user won't know it was because comment was empty.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Managed to sort it by simply adding in echo $error

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are talking about $error, if i am correct then you did not echo $error variable in your above mention code. One more thing add else part on if block "if ($comment != '')" else {$error.="no comment entered" }